# How to write approximations of a sequence $x_n = {1/3^n}$

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

Write three approximations of the sequence
${x_n} = {1/ 3^n}$, using the following scheme -

$P_0= 1, P_1 = 0.33332$ and $P_n = (6/5)P_{n-1} - (1/5)P_{n-2}$

for $n = 2, 3,\dots$

Further, make a table of errors for each of the three approximations in the following format for first ten errors
n      |x<sub>n</sub>-P<sub>n</sub>|
0
1
.
.
.
10

Comment: What have you done by yourself ?

Comment: I have no idea how to solve it. I asked my teacher for help who replied with "I don't know how to do it."

Comment: You know, that the sequence does not approximate $x_n$?

Comment: @Amzoti: This is a problem from my assignment, I have no way to verify if the problem is correct or not. I wrote it here as I have in my papers.

Comment: Page number 17 in this document. This is where the question is https://webservices.ignou.ac.in/assignments/bca/2014/january15/bca-r_5th_sem_assignments_july2014-jan15_crc.pdf

Comment: If I'm not missing something, that is the stupidest way to approximate $1/3^n$ since non of the three algorithms approximate it all.

Comment: Not sure if this is the limit, last year they asked to make a Java Applet program, the ancient technology.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure of the purpose of the exercise as none of the three items approximate the sequence, but here goes.

This is a just a straight plug in values and take differences for each $n$ for the four quantities.

Following this, we can setup the table and arrive at:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \text{n} & \text{$|$x$\_$n - r$\_$n$|$} & \text{$|$x$\_$n - p$\_$n$|$} & \text{$|$x$\_$n - q_n$|$} \\
 0 & 0.00004 & 0. & 0. \\
 1 & 0.133341 & 0.0000133333 & 0.133336 \\
 2 & 0.0711127 & 0.0888729 & 0.0711267 \\
 3 & 0.0290374 & 0.13628 & 0.0291152 \\
 4 & 0.0107457 & 0.155638 & 0.0111363 \\
 5 & 0.00379524 & 0.162801 & 0.00574835 \\
 6 & 0.00130774 & 0.165332 & 0.0110734 \\
 7 & 0.000444448 & 0.166203 & 0.0492726 \\
 8 & 0.000149856 & 0.1665 & 0.24429 \\
 9 & 0.0000502933 & 0.1666 & 1.22075 \\
 10 & 0.0000168327 & 0.166633 & 6.10353 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, you just have to write a program that outputs this table.